# How to change the text of a table cell while hovering using only CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if anyone in SO would be kind enough to assist me.  Using only CSS (most-likely CSS3), is there a way to change the inner HTML of a table cell while hovering over the element?  I have a numerical table with 49 cells (7 rows by 7 columns), and I would like the number in the first cell of the first row to change from number 1 to number 50, but only when hovering over the number 1 (i.e. - changing back to number 1 when not hovering).

I can do this with a "change innerHTML" function in JavaScript, but only when using a portion of the script inline with my HTML within the body of the document.  For various reasons, I cannot use any script or CSS inline, so this method of achieving my goal is not what I want to use (this goes beyond semantic reasons).  I would really rather avoid using any script at all for this effect because I think CSS3 handles effects more elegantly and selectively than JavaScript (i.e. - CSS3 Tooltips are much nicer than any script-based Tooltip).

I was just wondering if someone knew how to do this using CSS3 (maybe with the z-index, display: none; or positioning techniques somehow?}. I've played around with it, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I would use JavaScript if I didn't have to mix the script in with my Markup, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do that.

Anyone have ideas on how to go about this?  Thank you for your time.

*Update*

@ramsesoriginal
@hiphip

Thanks again.  I answered "Yes" to the *"Did this answer help you."*  I believe that is what you meant by *"as accepted"* **ramsesoriginal**; right?  Thanks **hiphip** for your answer as well.  I was playing around with styles like the code below, but it wasn't quite working out in the table cell the way I had hoped *(works nice with isolated images by the way)*.  I think I'll keep working on it though;  the more options, the better.

```
div.up {
   margin: 10px 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border: 1px solid rgb(170, 169, 169);
   overflow: hidden;
}   

div.up div {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   font-size: 13px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: center;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: left 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s linear;
  -o-transition: left 1s linear;
  transition: left 1s linear;
}

div.up div.one {
   z-index: 999;
}       

div.up:hover div.one {
     -webkit-transition: left 1s linear;
     -moz-transition: left 1s linear;
     -o-transition: left 1s linear;
     transition: left 1s linear;
     left: -99px;
}
```

Comment: What I meant was that there should be a tick below the voting buttons. If you click on it the question will be marked as answered (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ). And to your example: could you provide the `HTML`too, or even better, a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways, but both require some additional markup:

```
<td id="example1" class="hoverer"><span class="nohower">1</span><span class="hover">50</span></td>
```

with the styling

```
 #example1 .hover{
     display:none;
 }

 #example1 .nohower{
     display:block;
 }

 #example1:hover .hover{
     display:block;
 }

 #example1:hover .nohower{
     display:none;
 }
```

or

```
<td id="example2" class="hoverer"><span data-hover="50">1</span></td>
```

with the styling

```
 #example2:hover span:after{
     content:attr(data-hover);
 }
 #example2:hover span{
     width:1px;
     margin-left: -0.5em;/* adjust accoridng to font*/
 }
```

You can view a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/W8LQq/

Comment: Haha.  Thank you so much.  I knew it!  I was on the right track but I didn't have the time to follow through.  I was getting somewhat close when I was playing around with a variation on the CSS3 Tooltip.  I created two divs that sat on top of each other, using the z-index, relative and absolute positioning, and the transition properties, but I couldn't quite get them to do exactly what I wanted.  Thanks so much.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

CSS is only used for styling HTML. It has no access to the attributes of the HTML itself.

Comment: You could create some alternate text in the cell that is the same color as the background and thus not visible.  When you hover over it change the background color and the text becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this with only CSS

Answer (score 0):

With positioning:

```
<style>
    #outterdiv {
        position: relative;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border: 1px blue solid;
    }
    #innerdiv:hover {
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
    }
</style>

<div id="outterdiv">
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>50</div>
    </div>
</div>
```